# contenteditable - JQuery save content just to webpage (as well as adding and removing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Upon thorough research I was able to allow one data value to be edited and updated within my table. However, when I attempt to alter where the contenteditable can be edited, It removes my formatting of the table (it actually removes the table format completely, rendering my idea pointless.

Here is my current code.

```
              <div class="bs-docs-example">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>#</th>
                  <th>IRC Name</th>
                  <th>Ingame Name</th>
                  <th>Position</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>[Cr|m|nAl]</td>
                  <td id="content2" contenteditable="true">Herbalist</td>
                  <td>Aeterna Top</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td >2</td>
                  <td >bandido</td>
                  <td >Bananni</td>
                  <td >Aeterna Top</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>Funkystyle</td>
                  <td>Funkystyle</td>
                  <td>Aeterna Top</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <button id="save">Save Changes</button>

<!-- begin the script -->
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var theContent = $('#content2');// set the content

    $('#save').on('click', function () { // store the new content in localStorage when the button is clicked
        var editedContent = theContent.html();
        localStorage.newContent = editedContent;
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('newContent')) { // apply the newContent when it is exist ini localStorage
        theContent.html(localStorage.getItem('newContent'));
    }
</script>
```

Now, ideally I would like it to output like this screenshot below;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOoeI.png
With the column of "Ingame Name" editable.
Add Row/Remove Row, I'm wanting to implement too, but I'm not too sure if you can do it with such a simple HTML table.

My First question-
how would I make a particular row (i.e Ingame Name) be the only one editable? I'm terrible have Javascript/Jquery and my research unfortunately, only allows me to refine one row. (I know I could probably replicate the javascript/jquery, but surely there is an easier way?)

Second question-

Is it possible to actually add the ability for a HTML table to add/remove rows without having a database of some sort?

Thanks for any guidance in regards to this.

Comment: Can you add that in jsfiddle or something? So we can better know what resources you use.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3enz61xy/ JS Fiddle. I'd like to edit all ingame name rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making `td` editable you could wrap `div` inside `td` and make it editable and assign fixed `width` and `height` to div.

```
 .clEdit {
   width: 200px;
   /*Try chaging it as per need*/
   overflow: hidden;
  /*  try scroll with more height  */
  height: 15px;
  /*Try chaging it as per need*/
 }
```

Now there are 2 options either allow overflow to be hidden or scroll. You could examine the behavior and select either one. As a user friendly experience you could assign tooltip to div on hover or click so that whenever values inside div are being overflown user could see what are the current values inside.

```
 $(".clEdit").hover(function(e) {

   $(this).prop("title", $(this).html());

 });
```

Yes you could add/delete rows from table without DB if you know the values. `id` can be calculated from previous id value.

Adding/removing from table does not guarantee DB will be updated you need handle that.

On adding rows you need to bind event for contenteditable as well.

```
 $("#add").click(function() {
    //LOGIC TO ADD ROW TO TABLE

    var trRow = "<tr><td>" + ++idFirstCol + "</td><td>" + "SecondColValue" + "</td><td><div class='clEdit'>" + "ThirdColValue" + "</div></td>     <td> " + "LastColValue" + " </td></tr>";

$("#ConTable").append(trRow);
   $(".clEdit").hover(function(e) {
        $(this).prop("title", $(this).html());
   });
   $(".clEdit").prop('contenteditable', true);
});
```

You could refer to **JSFiddle** here. http://jsfiddle.net/8mt6d7bz/

Lmk if that answers your question

Comment: With my javascript for saving. I'm assuming it wouldn't work because it is based off of the css class?

Comment: @BrianElliott What do you mean? It does not matter if its based off class or id you can always save in localstorage or db.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/be3w2zfs/ - By this I mean, Should the save button work (logically). For some reason it doesn't though, not too sure what it wrong with it though

Comment: unable to see it for some reason. Says page doesn't exist.

Comment: @BrianElliott Make a note that row Id is static starting from 3 onwards. If you want to add new row with dynamic row ID make sure to update `js` function where it states rowId as 3 and assign the highest id available from table. Refer to questions on SO on to get last row of table. Then fetch first `td` child of row and get html out of that td.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. this has solved my issues. By rowID being static, does this mean that If I add a row from Machine A, then Add a row from Machine B. both rows would therefore be 4?

Comment: From anywhere everytime page is refreshed and new row is added it will be 4. Since in `js` add function it is hardcoded as `3` to make dynamic follow comment above.