# Javascript not running properly? (Ignoring my current html values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have some Javascript that will allow me to add to rows onto a currently existing HTML table, and save the changes. However, by default when I go onto the page, the table doesn't exist. However, When I've placed a breakpoint at a certain stage upon my script, the original table appears, but then defaults back to `Hello` and simply doesn't add a new row.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

**JQuery Import**

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.0-beta2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="ConTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>IRC Name</th>
                <th>Ingame Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>[Cr|m|nAl]</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='clEdit'>
                        Herbalist
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Aeterna Top</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >2</td>
                <td >bandido</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='clEdit'>
                        Bananni
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td >Aeterna Top</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Funkystyle</td>
                <td>
                    <div class='clEdit'>
                        Funkystyle
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>Aeterna Top</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="single-one">
    <button id="del" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Rows</button>
</div>
<div class="single-one">
    <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary">Add Rows</button>
</div>
<div class="single-one">
    <button id="save" class="btn btn-success">Save Changes</button>
</div>
<div id="divCon">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".clEdit").prop('contenteditable', true);
//Try with hover replace click with hover
$(".clEdit").hover(function (e) {
    $(this).prop("title", $(this).html());
});

var idFirstCol;
//var idFirstCol = 3;
if (localStorage.getItem('rowID'))
{ // apply the newContent when it is exist ini localStorage
    idFirstCol = localStorage.getItem('rowID');
}
else
{
    idFirstCol = 3; //As of now hardcoded to 3 for first load since HTML content has 3 rows
}

$("#add").click(function () {
    //LOGIC TO ADD ROW TO TABLE
    var trRow = "<tr><td>"
            + ++idFirstCol
            + "</td><td><div class='clEdit'>"
            + "SecondColValue"
            + "</div><td><div class='clEdit'>"
            + "ThirdColValue"
            + "</div></td><td><div class='clEdit'> "
            + "LastColValue"
            + "</div></td></tr>";


    $("#ConTable").append(trRow);
    $(".clEdit").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).prop("title", $(this).html());
    });

    $(".clEdit").prop('contenteditable', true);
});

var theContent = $('#ConTable');// set the content
$('#save').on('click', function () { // store the new content in localStorage when the button is clicked
    var editedContent = theContent.html();
    alert(editedContent);
    localStorage.newContent = editedContent;
    localStorage.rowID = idFirstCol;
});

if (localStorage.getItem('newContent'))
{ // apply the newContent when it is exist ini localStorage
    theContent.html(localStorage.getItem('newContent'));
}
```

**CSS**

```
.editable{ 
    background:#EAEAEA
}

.clEdit {
    width : 250px; /*Try chaging it as per need*/
    overflow : hidden; /*  try scroll with more height  */
    height : 25px;/*Try chaging it as per need*/
}
```

This works on JSFiddle but not on my computer, so I'm not entirely sure whats wrong (which I'm assuming its from my end. No errors appear within the Javascript upon running it. I've also attempted to try this in an empty website, however it still doesn't do what the javascript should do. (However the table does appear)

Does anyone understand where I am going wrong? I can provide screenshots to aid in my search for a solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/5g2xmsfp/ - to show what should happen.

Linked Question: [contenteditable - JQuery save content just to webpage (as well as adding and removing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095448/contenteditable-jquery-save-content-just-to-webpage-as-well-as-adding-and-rem)

Comment: if there are no errors thrown then it's likely you haven't wraped code in `$(document).ready` which fiddle does similar by default

Comment: Does nothing unfortunately adding $(document).ready

Comment: @BrianElliott What do you mean it doesnt work? How are you testing it?

Comment: You really should get in the habit of indenting your code and making it tidy.  It makes it far easier to read / troubleshoot.

Comment: What **does it do** on your computer? Also, you've broken the html / script pieces apart, it's always useful to see them together.  jQuery depends on things being loaded in a certain order, and it may be that your scripts on your actual page are not in the correct order.

Comment: It simply attempts to add a row (you see it add for under a millisecond), disappears again and "Hello" reappears.

Comment: Where is "Hello" coming from? That string doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea. If searched through everything. (Could it be a default value in localstorage?)

Comment: clear your browser cache and try. @BrianElliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider the behavior of localStorage. When user adds rows and saves it. It gets saved on his local machine specific to browser.

So lets say if user `A` accesses website and sees 3 rows by default. user will edit few content and add new row and save.

If user `B` accesses website page user will see 3 rows by default if he accesses it for first time.

Now If User A accesses website for second time from same browser user will see edited and added rows. But if user access it from different browser than before than again it shows default page with 3 rows only.

I think this is what is happening in your case. If you wish to save whole table you should save it by values on server and while displaying it read it from server and display it in table. It will be consistent for all users irrespective of browser.

Also wait for other users to guide on it.

Comment: By this thinking (as I never logically thought **localstorage** was infact, local (stupid me)), I thought to try it via C# using an ASP table to run it at the server, and hold information in a text file, then upon loading the page anywhere else, it'll read the text file with HTML. Alternative, and a route I may be more confident using. Your answer indirectly resolved my problem to find a different route to take. Thank you.

Comment: text file will work too on server. Try working around local db on server if you could do that.